# Basics on Vector Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The vorticity equation of fluid dynamics is written as

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\partial t}+(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{\omega}=(\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u},
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{\omega}=\nabla\times\mathbf{u}$ is the fluid vorticity and $\mathbf{u}$ is the fluid velocity.

Deduce that if $\mathbf{u}$ is two-dimensional (e.g. no component in $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ direction), then $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is constant.

I know that if $\mathbf{u}$ is two-dimensional, then $\mathbf{u}=(u_{1}(x,y),u_{2}(x,y),0)$, which implies

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\omega}=\nabla\times\mathbf{u}=(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(0)-\dfrac{\partial{u_{2}}}{\partial z},\dfrac{\partial{u_{1}}}{\partial z}-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(0),\dfrac{\partial{u_{2}}}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial{u_{1}}}{\partial y})=(0,0,\dfrac{\partial{u_2}}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial{u_1}}{\partial y}).
\end{align}

To show that $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is constant, $\dfrac{\partial{\boldsymbol{\omega}}}{\partial t}$ must be equal to $0$, which also means $(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{\omega}=0$ and $(\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}=0$. I am having a little difficulty in proving this, as whenever I try to evaluate the two differential operators above, I'd always end up with a vector that has a non-zero expression in at least one of the $\hat{\mathbf{x}},\hat{\mathbf{y}}$,or $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ components. Appreciate any help I can get, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can show $(\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}=0$

as $\boldsymbol{\omega}=\omega\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ therefore

$\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\nabla=\omega\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{}}{\partial z}$

and as $\mathbf{u}(x,y)$

implies $\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{\mathbf{u}}}{\partial z}=0$,

which implies $(\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}=0$

I'm not sure yet how to show $(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{\omega}=0$ yet but will edit it in, if i work it out.